# Show and hide loading spinner with Angular on HTTP

Tags: angular

I spent the last days trying to move from AngularJS to Angular. I already have a web app and I want to rewrite it for exercise. One of the features I had in the old one was a loading spinner during a HTTP request. I searched on Google and online tutorials to see how I could do that with Angular and I opted for a service. Here is the code:

**spinner.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export interface ISpinnerState {
  show: boolean
}

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private _spinnerSubject = new Subject();

  spinnerState = <Observable<ISpinnerState>>this._spinnerSubject;

  show() {
    this._spinnerSubject.next(<ISpinnerState>{ show: true });
  }

  hide() {
    this._spinnerSubject.next(<ISpinnerState>{ show: false });
  }
}
```

**spinner.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { ISpinnerState, SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'loading-spinner',
  template: `
    <div
      class="spinner">
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`.spinner {position: absolute;left: 46%;top: 12%;background-color:black;width:50px;height:50px}`]
})

export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  visible = false;

  private _spinnerStateChanged: Subscription;

  constructor(private _spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._spinnerStateChanged = this._spinnerService.spinnerState
      .subscribe((state: ISpinnerState) => this.visible = state.show);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._spinnerStateChanged.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

At the moment, it is just a black square so I can test it. After that, I will add a proper loading icon. Here is another service that I call it during an HTTP request.

**apartment.service.ts**

```
....other stuff

@Injectable()
export class ApartmentService {

  constructor(
    private _http: Http,
    private _spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

getApartments() {
    this._spinnerService.show();
    return this._http.get(API + 'apartments')
      .map((response: Response) => <Apartment[]>response.json().apartments)
      //.catch(this._exceptionService.catchBadResponse)
      .finally(() => this._spinnerService.hide());
  }

}
```

The problem is that the spinner is always visible. Not only on the loading process. I cannot see what I have done wrong. Any idea?

Comment: I think `spinnerState = <Observable<ISpinnerState>>this._spinnerSubject;` should be `spinnerState = <Observable<ISpinnerState>>this._spinnerSubject.asObservable();`

Comment: Where are you providing the services?

Comment: Where are you using `visible` to show/hide the spinner?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If I change the code, I have this error on: `[ts] Property 'asObservable‌' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>'.` What do you mean where I am providing the services?

Comment: That's weird. I'm sure that should just work. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the binding to show/hide depending on the `visible` state:

```
<div *ngIf="visible"
  class="spinner">
</div>
```

Comment: I imported the HostBinding, added above the `visible=false` on the component but still the same behaviour. Spinner visible all the time.

Comment: Holy... I cannot believe that I missed the `*ngIf`...I spent 2 days trying to figure what is wrong on the code and didn't check at all those 2 lines of code :P It works now :)